# Executar função que retorne vários valores e com base nestes fazer o SELECT principal - SQL Server

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, funções, tabela-banco-de-dados, back-end

Tenho a seguinte função em SQL Server que retorna o nome de cada coluna da minha tabela:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FiltraNomeColunas(@FiltroColuna VARCHAR(200))
RETURNS VARCHAR
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Retorno VARCHAR(200); 

        SET @Retorno = (
                            SELECT c.name as NomeColuna
                            FROM sys.tables as t
                            INNER JOIN sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
                            WHERE c.name LIKE @FiltroColuna
                        );  
    RETURN @Retorno
END
```

Preciso dar um select nas colunas retornadas por esta função.

Estou tentando fazer da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT 
table_c1_di.E3TimeStamp AS Data_Hora,
dbo.FiltraNomeColunas('%DISJ%')

FROM table_c1_di 
JOIN c1_do.dbo.table_c1_do ON CAST(table_c1_do.E3TimeStamp AS DATETIME2(0)) =  CAST(table_c1_di.[E3TimeStamp] AS DATETIME2(0)) 

WHERE (table_c1_do.E3TimeStamp  >= @DataInicial  AND table_c1_do.E3TimeStamp <= @DataFinal)

ORDER BY table_c1_do.E3TimeStamp  DESC
```

Porém, da forma como estou puxando esta apresentando erro pois a função retorna mais de um resultado.

Gostaria de saber alguma forma que eu posso estar fazendo/buscando esta função para que a mesma retorna mais valores, e como estes valores de retorno são o nome das colunas desta tabela, que o select principal conclua a consulta com base nos valores de retorno.

Comment: No seu caso seria melhor usar uma `stored procedure` no lugar de uma `function`. Uma `function` na sua essência, deve retornar um único valor (veja exemplos como `GETDATE()` e `LOWER()`). Como você precisa retornar mais de um valor, use uma `stored procedure`, que pode retornar o resultado de um `select` com muitos valores.

Comment: Uma outra solução seria declarar a `function` retornando uma `table`, ou Table-Valued retorno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui, um exemplo usando Table-Value retorno.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FiltraNomeColunas(@FiltroColuna VARCHAR(200))
RETURNS @nomes TABLE 
(
    Nome VARCHAR(200)
)
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @nomes SELECT c.name as NomeColuna
                            FROM sys.tables as t
                            INNER JOIN sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
                            WHERE c.name LIKE @FiltroColuna

    RETURN
END
```

Isso deve resolver o retorno, que precisa ser mais de uma linha.